# Rename the sub-sub-directories of a directory named _QWE

Tags: bash, command-line, find

I can run a command in all directories named `_QWE` using:

```
find . -name '_QWE' -type d -execdir touch {}/1234.txt \;
```

However, I need to run `-execdir rename 's!^\./(\d+ -)\s(\d+\.)!$1!' {} \;` in all the immediate sub-directories of `_QWE` to rename the sub-directories of the sub-directories of `_QWE`.

I mean suppose I have a directory structure like:

```
├── folder_1
│   └── _QWE
│       ├── Course 1
│       │   ├── 1 - Introduction
│       │   ├── 2 - 1. Basics of Course 1
│       │   ├── 3 - 2. Conclusion of Course 1
│       ├── Course 2
│       │   ├── 1 - Introduction
│       │   ├── 2 - 1. Basics of Course 2
│       │   ├── 3 - 2. Conclusion of Course 2
├── folder_2
│   └── folder_3
│      └── _QWE
│          ├── Course X1
│          │   ├── 1 - Introduction
│          │   ├── 2 - 1. Basics of Course X1
│          │   ├── 3 - 2. Conclusion of Course X1
│          ├── Course X2
│          │   ├── 1 - Introduction
│          │   ├── 2 - 1. Basics of Course X2
│          │   ├── 3 - 2. Conclusion of Course X2
```

Here I want to rename:

```
1 - Introduction
2 - 1. Basics of Course 1
3 - 2. Conclusion of Course 1
1 - Introduction
2 - 1. Basics of Course 2
3 - 2. Conclusion of Course 2
1 - Introduction
2 - 1. Basics of Course X1
3 - 2. Conclusion of Course X1
1 - Introduction
2 - 1. Basics of Course X2
3 - 2. Conclusion of Course X2
```

Here for example, `3 - 2. Conclusion of Course X2` will be renamed to `3 - Conclusion of Course X2`. This is what `'s!^\./(\d+ -)\s(\d+\.)!$1!'` does.

Just to be clear, `3 - 2. Conclusion of Course X2` is a directory name and not file name.

How can I do that?

**Update 1:**

I could get the paths using:

```
for dir in $(find . -name '_QWE' -type d)/*/ ; do echo $dir ; done
```

or,

```
for dir in $(find . -name '_QWE' -type d)/*/ ; do (cd "$dir"; pwd); done
```

But,

```
for dir in $(find . -name '_QWE' -type d)/*/*/ ; do rename 's!^\./(\d+ -)\s(\d+\.)!$1!' $dir ; done
```

Not yielding any output.

Comment: `for dir in $(find ...)` is a bad idea.  See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice).   Use find's `-exec`/`-execdir` or use `readarray`/`mapfile` to populate an array with NUL-separated output from find, then iterate over the array.   BTW, `rename` produces no output on stdout unless you tell it to with the `-v` option.  Also, if you want only the *immediate* sub-dirs of _QWE then use find's `-maxdepth 1` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `-path` modifier to pick out directories immediately under the matching directories:

```
find . -depth -type d -path '*/_QWE/*/*' ! -path '*/_QWE/*/*/*' -exec rename 's!(/\d+)\s+-\s+\d+\.\s+([^/]*)$!$1 $2!' {} +
```

I have modified your RE slightly to anchor it to the filename component of the matched path. (For PCRE expressions as used here, `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters; `\d+` matches one or more digits; `[^/]*` matches a run of zero or more characters *except* `/`.)

Using your example tree of directories, here is the corresponding output when using `rename -n`:

```
./folder_1/_QWE/Course 1/2 - 1. Basics of Course 1 renamed as ./folder_1/_QWE/Course 1/2 Basics of Course 1
./folder_1/_QWE/Course 1/3 - 2. Conclusion of Course 1 renamed as ./folder_1/_QWE/Course 1/3 Conclusion of Course 1
./folder_1/_QWE/Course 2/2 - 1. Basics of Course 1 renamed as ./folder_1/_QWE/Course 2/2 Basics of Course 1
./folder_1/_QWE/Course 2/3 - 2. Conclusion of Course 1 renamed as ./folder_1/_QWE/Course 2/3 Conclusion of Course 1
./folder_2/folder_3/_QWE/Course X1/2 - 1. Basics of Course 1 renamed as ./folder_2/folder_3/_QWE/Course X1/2 Basics of Course 1
./folder_2/folder_3/_QWE/Course X1/3 - 2. Conclusion of Course 1 renamed as ./folder_2/folder_3/_QWE/Course X1/3 Conclusion of Course 1
./folder_2/folder_3/_QWE/Course X2/2 - 1. Basics of Course 1 renamed as ./folder_2/folder_3/_QWE/Course X2/2 Basics of Course 1
./folder_2/folder_3/_QWE/Course X2/3 - 2. Conclusion of Course 1 renamed as ./folder_2/folder_3/_QWE/Course X2/3 Conclusion of Course 1
```

For testing, I also added a sample set of directories using the same names under a `folder_4` but not under a directory `_QWE`. As expected these were correctly ignored.

Comment: I need to rename the sub-directories. It finds the sub-directories if I use `find -type d -path '*/_QWE/*' ! -path '*/_QWE/*/*'`. For example, `./folder_1/_QWE/FolderName`. Here I need to change the `FolderName`. But then the rename command does not change anything.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail the question implies you want to rename files. Update the question to make it clear what you want - ideally including some examples - and I'll see if I can amend the answer to match the new requirement. In particular make it clear that you want to rename subdirectories of `_QWE`, if that indeed is what you want to do

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: The solution is `find -type d -path '*/_QWE/*/*'  ! -path '*/_QWE/*/*/*' -execdir rename 's!^\./(\d+ -)\s(\d+\.)!$1!' {} \;`, Thank you very much.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail I've updated my question to match your updated answer